# Problem claiming my matrices are incompatible with each other for matrix multiplication but are both the same length

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication

I am calling my function:

```
function [h,y,e] = f_adap(x,d,h0,mu)
    h=h0; P=length(h);
    N=length(x);
    y=zeros(1,N);e=y;
    rP = 0:-1:-P+1;
    for k=P:N
        xx=x(k+rP);
        disp(length(h'))
        y(k)=xx*(h');
        e(k)=d(k)-y(k);
        h=h+mu*e(k)*xx;
    end
end
```

It is providing me the following error message

```
'Error using  * 
Incorrect dimensions for matrix multiplication. Check that the number of columns in the first
matrix matches the number of rows in the second matrix. To operate on each element of the matrix
individually, use TIMES (.*) for elementwise multiplication.'
```

On this line:

```
y(k)=xx*(h');
```

I have checked the length of both xx and h' which are both 50 so I am unsure as to why this error keeps persisting.

I have also tried using .* and just h instead of h' however that provides this error: Unable to perform assignment because the left and right sides have a different number of
elements.

Any idea why these errors occur?

Comment: We can't know what you want unless you explain what the lines are supposed to do. you can indeed not multiply a `50x1` matrix with a `50x1` matrix, due to how matrix multiplication works. You can however, element-wise multiply them, so the result is another `50x1` matrix. But indeed, you can not store `50x1` values in a `1x1` space (`y(k)` is `1x1`). This is *why* they occur, but unless you explain what you want in each line, we can't help fix them

Comment: A hint for MATLAB: forget `length`, use `size`

Comment: @AnderBiguri Thanks that makes sense. When I used size both h' and xx were 50x1 so that explains why they didn't work. However, the size of just h is 1x50 and when I try using that instead of h' it still provides the same area.

Comment: I might be wrong but I thought you could do matrix multiplication with a 50x1 and a 1x50 matrix

Comment: Your question could be greatly improved by removing the function entirely and creating two dummy variables of the appropriate sizes that reproduce the problem. Only then would we be able to see exactly what you're doing and reproduce the issue.

Comment: @A.wilson of course you can, but if MATLAB is erroring its because those are not the sizes you are giving to the multiplication (and thus, my suggestion to check `size` rather than `length`, as the second will return `50` for both `50x1` and `1x50`). Also note that the result of  a `50x1` times a `1x50` is a `50x50`

Answer (score 1):

The way to debug these types of problems is to use the MATLAB debugger. First, type this at the command prompt:

```
dbstop if error
```

Then run your code. When the error occurs, the code will pause at the line that is causing the error with all variables intact. Examine the variables on that line to determine their sizes and you will find the culprits. Then you can backtrack in your code to figure out why they are not the sizes you expected.